# Python index x is out bounds for axis 0 size of n

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hey guys trying to attempt to create my own basic hockey analytic program. While trying to get all my information I gave been stumped by this error. Tried looking a bunch of things up and nothing seemed to work for me. I am new to using pandas and numpy. Any help would be much appreciated , thank you!!

```
import numpy as np


nyr_sched = nhl2021_22_sched[(nhl2021_22_sched['home_team'] == 'NYR') | (nhl2021_22_sched['away_team'] == 'NYR')]
nyr_sched

for game in nyr_sched:
    nyr_GID = nyr_sched['game_id']

nyr_GID = np.array(nyr_GID)
nyr_GID.tolist()
nyr_GID
```

Which prints `array([2021020004, 2021020011, 2021020023, 2021020035, 2021020059,...])`

But I run into a problem here.

```
for i in nyr_GID:
    nyr_GID[i] = nyr_GID[i][5:]
    print("Game {} ID is {}".format(i, nyr_GID[i]))
```

I am looking to remove the first 5 numbers from each ID in the list so instead of `202102004` it is `20004`.
However I get an error stating I am trying to access the `20212004` index. Here is the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/v8/z9h_xhmj1t38rzq1351q_my40000gn/T/ipykernel_13046/4170336391.py in <module>
      1 count = 0
      2 for i in nyr_GID:
----> 3     nyr_GID[i] = nyr_GID[i][5:]
      4     print("Game {} ID is {}".format(i, nyr_GID[i]))

IndexError: index 2021020004 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 82
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
for i in range(len(nyr_GID)):
    nyr_GID[i] = str(nyr_GID[i])[5:]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...unfortunately this return IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: Try converting each item to a string, like I have done in my edited comment. If you want the items as ints, you can convert them back after.

Comment: Awesome thank you it worked, I really appreciate it I knew I was close and it was a simple fix. You rock!!!

Answer (score 1):

The i in

> for i in nyr_GID:

refers to the elements in nyr_GID.

To get the corresponding indices use :
range(nyr_GID.size)

Tiny code snippet :

```
test = np.array([234, 345, 456])
for i in test:
  print(i, test[i])

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module> 
IndexError: index 234 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

#correct version
for i in range(test.size):
    print(i, test[i])

0 234 1 345 2 456
```

In your code, you'll also need
`str(nyr_GID[i])` to convert the ith element to string